# How to calculate the volume of intersection of two cylinders which have radius $r$ and $R$ $(r\le R)?$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, volume, convolution

The cylinders have their axis meet at right angle. I try to use integral to derive the equation but I have a hard time visualizing the edge of intersection. Could someone help?

Comment: For the general case, you can see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338708/volume-of-the-intersection-of-two-cylinders) question. For a particular case, you can see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/498800) answer.

Comment: Idea that maybe will work: write the big cylinder as $z = \pm f(x,y)$. The volume will be 2(integral of $f$ on the domain $x^2+y^2\le r$). Try first in cilyndrical coordinates.

Comment: Aside from the existing links, this comment is to link this post as one of the [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868) to the current choice of [mother/target post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167660).